# Restart Task after CancellationToken expires 3 seconds c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
public  void LoadData()
{
    try
    {
        var cst = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

        var result = Task.Run(() => LongRunningMethodCall ),cst.Token)
            .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                switch (t.Status)
                {
                    case TaskStatus.Canceled:
                        LoadData();
                        break;
                    case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                        var result = t.Result;
                        break;
                }


            }, cst.Token,TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, _uiScheduler);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
    }
}
```

I need to call LoadData() method Aynchronously , This Task is specified with TimeOut with 3 seconds.
If Task is not Completed within 3 seconds, I need to perform   Rerty operation for 10 times to get the t.result

Comment: Okay, so change from a recursive call to a loop so you can limit the number of retries...

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void LoadData()
    {
        string result = null;

        for ( i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )
        {
            try
            {
                var cst = new CancellationTokenSource( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 3 ) );
                var task = Task.Run( () => LongRunningMethodCall( cst.Token ), cst.Token );
                var result = task.Result;
            }
            catch ( AggregateException ex )
            {
                // Check that all exceptions is a OperationCanceledException
                if ( !ex.InnerExceptions.All( e => e is OperationCanceledException ) )
                    throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

You should process `CancellationToken` in your `LongRunningMethodCall` to cancel task. Example of task cancellation:

```
if ( token.IsCancellationRequested )
   token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

More detail about task cancellation you make read in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children